# In Tableau, I would like to know how to display select values from multiple rows in just one row, selecting values from two different tables

Tags: tableau-api, z-index, calculated-field

From my attached Tableau screenshot, I'd like to select only the 'Yes' values from Calc 1 where there is also a 'Yes' value from Calc 2 and display them in the same row for each unique Encounter Number. Note Calc 1 is derived from a different table than Calc 2, but my real life example has HIPAA data so I cannot share that file but have mocked up the attached, so hopefully there is a way to display all Yes, Yes values in the same row knowing there are two different sources of data which is why you see null values in the example. Can I create a calculated field that would accomplish this? The correct end result would simply look like this:

Encounter Number Calc 1 Calc 2

1000             Yes     Yes

1005             Yes     Yes

1015             Yes     Yes

1020             Yes     Yes

[Tableua screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9DJZ.png)

[Tableau screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcAOG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create two new LOD calculations fixed to the Encounter Number to get a single value for each one. For example:

```
{ FIXED [Encounter Number] : MAX([Calc 1] = "Yes")}
```

and

```
{ FIXED [Encounter Number] : MAX([Calc 2] = "Yes")}
```

These calculations will look at all the rows for each encounter, check if any of them are "Yes" and if so it will return "True".

Now use those new calculations instead of your original calculations in your table and you will get a single row for each encounter that shows if the calculation was ever "Yes" for the encounter. Output:

Encounter Number    New Calc 1  New Calc 2
1000    True    True
1005    True    True
1010    True    False
1015    True    True
1020    True    True
1025    False   True
1030    False   False

From there it's as easy as filtering on your new calculations to keep only the ones that were yes for both:

Encounter Number    New Calc 1  New Calc 2
1000    True    True
1005    True    True
1015    True    True
1020    True    True

*Note: I kept to booleans but you can either re-alias them to "Yes"/"No" or you can change the calculation to output to "Yes"/"No".*

Comment: Thanks so much Keshia, the Fixed calculations helped!  I added a Tableau screenshot 2 to my post, I wonder if you could help with one last question?  I have added a third column I'll call "Type", where I need that value along with the Calc 1 and Calc 2 "True"/"True" values.  Because I need the value that lives in Calc 1 and the Type as well, I lose the Type when I line up the "True"/"True" values and get the Type value of null after filtering.  Is there a was to pull the Type value into all the rows for each encounter?   Many thanks!

Comment: No problem! Yes, you can do this with the same type of calculation! Basically, a FIXED  LOD (Level Of Detail) calculation allows you to aggregate data at a specific level, and therefore that value gets repeated on every line of whatever you've "fixed" it to.  

So for you, the aggregation can be MAX([Type]) and the level is still [Encounter Number] like this:  {FIXED [Encounter Number] : MAX([Type])}  

You can check out this whitepaper for a more in-depth overview of LOD expressions: https://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/whitepaper_lod_eng_high.pdf